# Problem with being able to access certain elements in GridView -> TemplateField -> EditItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I have this problem with being able to access certain elements in

```
GridView -> TemplateField -> EditItemTemplate.
```

To be more clear, I have textbox and button
(`in GridView -> TemplateField -> EditItemTemplate`) and only one of them must be visible depending on operation. If I want to edit, button must be visible and if I want to add new user then textbox must be visible. I have added my aspx code for you to check and also C# code-behind. The method in C# code is the one which gets called immidiately when I press "Edit" button which lets to edit account details and permissions for one user. And I want that this method would decide whenever to show textbox or button (I have IsUserInsertMode property for that.)
I would be really grateful for someone who would help me out with this.

```
      <asp:GridView CssClass="grid" ID="gridUsers" runat="server"
       AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id"
       DataSourceID="dsrcUserList" GridLines="None"
       OnRowCommand="gridUsers_RowCommand" OnDataBound="gridUsers_DataBound"
       OnRowUpdating="gridUsers_Updating" OnRowUpdated="gridUsers_Updated" EnableModelValidation="True">
               <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   *******
                                </ItemTemplate>

                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                        
                                   **NEED REFERENCES TO THESE TWO ITEMS IN ORDER TO SET THEIR VISIBILITY**
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnEditPassword" Text="Change" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnEditPassword_Click" Visible="false"/> 
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>' Width="74px" MaxLength="50" Visible="true" />

                                 </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                                 **LOTS OF CHECKBOXES LIKE THOSE**
                                 <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="AccessTowsRelease" HeaderText="TowsRelease" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                            </asp:CheckBoxField>

                                 <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="AccessTowsView" HeaderText="TowsView" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                            </asp:CheckBoxField>

                                 <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="AccessSMS" HeaderText="SMS"
                                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                            </asp:CheckBoxField>

                                 **MY EDIT BUTTON**
                                 <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link"
                                  ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Edit"
                                  CancelText="Cancel" UpdateText="Save" />
         
               </Columns>             
      </asp:GridView>
```

> C# code-behind (I have added some of the stuff that I have tried)

```
// this is called when I press some button which lets me to edit one user data including password
// but when I want to change password, there should be button which would redirect to different 
// window to do the password change procedure.
// And when I want to add new user there should be textbox for password, not the button.
protected void gridUsers_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //Found the way to get the index of current row (represents one row of information which is visible for the client in browser)
    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    
    //if those would be working I wouldn't be here asking for help
    btnEditPassword.Visible = true;
    txtPassword.Visible = false;
    
    
    //Can't cast 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'
    Button btnEditPassword = (Button)((GridViewRow)sender).FindControl("btnEditPassword");
    
    //every attempt to use FindControl gets me null
    Button btnEditPassword = (Button)this.gridUsers.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("btnEditPassword");
    
    // my way to check if it works - if its null then I do can't anything (prints to browser console).
    if (btnEditPassword != null) Response.Write("<script>console.log('not null')</script>");
    else Response.Write("<script>console.log('null')</script>");
}
```

Comment: Can you include your code showing where the edit button is located and what event its calling?

Comment: Thank you for answering @Homungus. I have edited the code to include where "Edit" button takes its place. Somehow I'm not sure exactly what event is being called but by using primitive debugging methods (can't use proper debugger because I'm editing this on server and using Notepad++, it sucks, I know) like printing to console, I have found that method that I have shown here is called first after button "Edit" is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RowCommand`-event is raised too early for your case. It's raised before the row is going into edit mode, that's why you don't find the controls of your edit-item-template.

First change your markup to handle the `RowDataBound`-event:

```
<asp:GridView ... OnRowDataBound="gridUsers_OnRowDataBound" ...>
```

Then handle this in the `OnRowDataBound`-event like this:

```
protected void gridUsers_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    // check if row is in edit state
    if ((e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit) || (e.Row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Alternate | DataControlRowState.Edit))) {
        
        // look for the control in the row
        Button btnEditPassword = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnEditPassword");
    }
}
```

Comment: No overload for 'gridUsers_DataBound' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'.       
I think thats because I have only EventArgs (from BaseDataBoundControl.OnDataBound(EventArgs) I think, not sure though) and not GridViewRowEventArgs.

Comment: Edited answer: you need the RowDataBound event instead of the DataBound event.

Comment: Okay, I just added OnRowDataBound = "gridUsers_RowDataBound" to asp:GridView attributes and also added appropriate method to code behind, and button seems not to be null anymore :)) UPDATE: IT WORKS :)))))) Very grateful